# How to send variable value in POST Method in Drupal

Tags: 7, webforms

How to send variable value to another page by using POST Method in Drupal?

Comment: Just create a form. Or use [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7)

Comment: yes I have create webform but when I am sending redirecting page to another page i.e i want to transfer particular value to another page but it is not going by POST method . it is going GET method only what to do?

Comment: GET or POST is just method of the form. I don't know why your form using GET, because usually forms use the POST method. But you can change property 'method' for $form via the form_alter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would just be a standard form with post as the method.

```
<form method="post" action="/other-page">
  <input type="text" name="yourfield" value="Value">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```